# Build failed 'A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'. in React native project

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I am trying to run project with command,

```
npx react-native run-android
```

and found this as an error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Documents\project\project_Workspace\projectname\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 69
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.

> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s
stuck to resolve this error.
Help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 3):

this problem happened in windows because of slashes

in your project folder navigate to `android` and open `local.properties` file

replace

```
sdk.dir=C:\Users\\<userName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

with

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\<userName>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

and it will work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this version

```
"react-native-reanimated": "2.0.0-rc.3"
```

It's worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, updating to reanimated@2.11.0 fixed my compile error
I am using react-native 0.69.3.

Answer (score 0):

As mention earlier this work

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\<userName>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```